# Eigenvalues of Infinite Dimensional Matrix

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics, operators, hilbert-space, eigenvalue

If I take a infinite-dimensional square matrix, what can I say about its eigenvalue spectrum? Will they have a discrete infinity of eigenvalues or continuous infinity of them?

Comment: discussed in many other questions, see e.g.:
http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/95193/
http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/68639/ (for normalizability)
http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/98462/ (for the definition of different bases - defines the infinite dimensional matrix)

Answer (score 2):

Infinite matrices, if properly handled, are nothing but  linear operators (either bounded or unbounded) on the Hilbert space $\ell^2(\mathbb N)$. So they can have point spectrum, continuous spectrum, residual spectrum just in view of the general theory of operators in general Hilbert spaces.